# Why is sed giving me this error: ... unknown command: `^'

Tags: sed

I would like sed to remove empty lines from a file.  I used this command:

```
cat file | sed '; ^$ ; d'
```

and was given the following error:

```
 sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `^'
```

Why is this happening?  Isn't sed supposed to interpret `^` as "the beginning of the line"?  If so, why am I getting this error message?

Comment: You didn't give sed a command, like 's' for search & replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (more) correct way is

```
cat file | sed '/^$/d'
```

But I am sure people will have lots of answers to the way of deleting empty lines.

Comment: What about this command makes it "more correct"?

Comment: It works? At least for me ;-)

Comment: When you use semicolons then you are telling `sed` that there are multiple commands to execute, so sed is expecting a seperate command, like `d`, inbetween each semicolon.